# How to hide console window in python PyQt GUI application

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have developed an application using Python 2.6, PyQt4.

We complied to `.pyc` and created a launcher to run this script and placed it in central location so that every one has access to it.

We found a console window is opening along with our application. So we changed the extension of launcher to `.pyw` and we achieved the desired solution.

The issue is if we are running this application and lock the system for long time, then the application is getting hanged. And when we use `.py` its not hanging.

So need a solution to hide the console window in with `.py`

Comment: Are you on Windows? What is the launcher -- a Windows shortcut maybe?

Comment: @JanneKarila Ya i am on Windows. Launcher contains `from script import class` `app = class()` `app.show()`

Comment: This answers your question, but I don't think your hanging problem depends on the `w` in the file name http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Comment: @hus787 i dont want to use `.pyw` its hanging. explained in my question

Comment: @JanneKarila Let me know is i can hide the terminal window (Console window) Your link again directs it to `pythonw.exe`

Comment: Maybe the program outputs something to stdout or stderr. Try to redirect them: `pythonw.exe launcher.py >NUL 2>NUL`

Answer (score 0):

to run PyQt app (with .py extension) by double click and do not see any console window just bind .py with pythonw.exe

do it in `cmd` (set proper path to pythonW.exe):

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File=C:\Python33\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
```

then just click on your py file.

BUT
I think that hanging you mentioned is related to pythonw.exe